# Datatables - return same pagination length on back button

Tags: laravel, datatables

Using Laravel Datatables
I feed Datatables with this function in controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
    
    if ($request->ajax()) {
    
        $data = Claims::with(array('customers' => function($query) {
            $query->select(
               'id', 'contr_nom', 'contr_cog', 'targa','email', 'gcliente', 'polizza', 'iban', 'int_iban'
            );
        })
        )->whereHas('refunds', function($query) {
            $query
                ->whereNotNull('num_pre')
                ->where('date_liq', '=', '0000-00-00')
                ->orderBy('claims_id', 'ASC');
        })->get();

        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('action', function($row) {
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dettaglio_'.$row->id.'" 
                    data-id_Claim="'.$row->id.'" 
                    data-dossier="'.$row->dossier.'"
                    data-contr_nom="'.$row->customers->contr_nom.'"
                    data-contr_cog="'.$row->customers->contr_cog.'"
                    data-targa="'.$row->customers->targa.'"
                    data-email="'.$row->customers->email.'"
                    data-gcliente="'.$row->customers->gcliente.'"
                    data-polizza="'.$row->customers->polizza.'"
                    data-iban="'.$row->customers->iban.'"
                    data-int_iban="'.$row->customers->int_iban.'"
                    class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Dettaglio</a>';

                return $btn;
            })->rawColumns(['action'])->make(true);
        }
    return view('pages.compta');
}
```

If I click on detail button I enter the detail-page, but when I return back to datatables it always refresh the first page.

Is there a way to return back to same page of the last row button selected?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You _could_ use `target="_blank"` to force the detail to open as a new tab/page, but that's more of a bandaid solution, and I'm not sure if that would even work with your `javascript:void(0)` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's simple. Just use stateSave option on your data tables.

Take this for reference

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  stateSave: true,
  stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data) {
      localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance, JSON.stringify(data) )
  },
  stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
    return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'DataTables_' + settings.sInstance ) )
  }
});
```

Comment: Great! it works but a way to indicate also last selected row? mmmm

Comment: Ok now....I added Row selection but it dont seem to keep with statesave........Why?

Comment: Yes you can but you will have to write code on statesacecallback and stateloadcallback

Comment: ok i resolved with this http://live.datatables.net/fetunese/1/edit

Comment: One way might be to save the row selections in javacript's sessionStorage object (or localStorage if you want them to be able to close the page and browse back again)