# Custom lengthMenu when page reloads in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, yajra-datatable

I am using yajra datatable with Laravel, and i want to make custom lenghMenu in datatable custom as in if user select an option from select menu and page reloads or user come back from another page then that selected option should be selected when this scenario happens.

This is what i tried, it works absolutely fine but when page reloads it goes to default option, i.e  "show 10 entries".

```
var oTable = $('#table')

$('#btn-filter').on('click', function(e) {
    oTable.draw();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thankx in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the DataTables [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option. "_State saving - restore table state on page reload._" See also [this overview](https://datatables.net/blog/2012-01-16) - although it is a bit out-of-date, now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datatables - return same pagination length on back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225902/datatables-return-same-pagination-length-on-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably save the length to database on page length change(with ajax)  and then load it from there on page load.

Otherwise it will load the default length from your javascript or wherever you have it stored currently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).